# Google Python API spreadsheet row /column count

Tags: python, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

The question is, can I retrieve a count of the columns? I mean, I can get a worksheet feed using this:

```
feed = self.gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed( self.spreadsheet_id )
```

and take it's `<ns1:rowCount>` or `<ns1:colCount>` tags values, but is there a way to retrieve it directly? Like `feed.entry[ number ].rowCount` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work

```
num_rows = int( feed.entry[ number].row_count.text )
```